# Natural sorting with LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, natural-sort

I've tried to implement natural sorting with LINQ to Entities, using the equivalent of this SQL statement:

```
ORDER BY case when name like '[0-9]%' then 1 else 0 end, name
```

My LINQ query is:

```
query.OrderByDescending(a => a.Name.StartsWith("[0-9]") ? 1 : 0)
```

LINQ to Entities though is adding a tilde (~) in the pattern.

It's generating an SQL query like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (Extent1.name LIKE '~[0-9]%'  escape '~') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [C1], name
        from accounts extent1
         order by c1 asc
```

How can I remove tilde (~) that has been appended after, like **'~[0-9]%'**?

Comment: You don't because there's nothing wrong. `[` is a special  character that needs escaping, and that's what EF does. The query is correct as is. You asked for names that start with the exact string `[0-9]`. If you don't get results, it's because there is no line that starts with the exact string `[0-9]`

Comment: I am getting result in sql server after removing tilde(~) that is appended. Its not being escaped.

Comment: Your query asks for names that start with `[0-9]` **EXACTLY**. You ask for `[0-9]George` and `[0-9]Pete`, not for `0George`. By removing the escape character you execute a completely different query. You can't use pattern matching with `StartsWith`. Were you trying to find names that start with a number?

Comment: I have added case then statement, here I want first it should show alphabetic name than its should show the name that is being start from any number.

Comment: correct, I am trying to match pattern using StartWith, What should I do for the same?

Comment: Actually, you should explain *why* you want this statement in your code - you display numbers first, which is what you get when you order in ascending order already. Why not just `OrderBy(a=>a.Name)`? The various techniques to use `LIKE` from a Linq to Entities query (eg SqlFunctions.PatIndex) probably won't work here

Comment: OrderBy(a=> a.Name) gives the result like sql server gives by default. Here I want to first alphabetic name then those name which start from any number. e.g Abhi, Jon, Pete, 01Pete, 12Mark like this.

Comment: Only removing tilde from sql server is giving correct result, but don't know how to remove from Linq

Comment: SQL Server doesn't order *anything* unless you specify some order. And numbers come before letters when you order in ascending order. In any case, `StartsWith` checks for an exact string, it doesn't offer pattern matching. It's *not* an EF function. `String.StartsWith` is translated to `LIKE 'x%'` where `x` is treated as a literal. You are using the wrong function for this specific job

Comment: In any case, what you tried won't have the effect you want. It will display names that start with a number *first* and all other rows in the order they are returned by the query processor without any effort to order them.

Comment: but also its not showing the names that is started with numbers.

Comment: You've run into the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have a problem with X (use natural sorting) and try solution Y ( a formula in the ORDER BY clause) so when Y fails, you ask about it, not X. There are other ways to perform natural sorting in SQL Server which may or may not work with EF. Eg, [the last solution in this article](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/solutions-t-sql-sorting-challenge) uses a `hierarchyid` which is only available as an extenstion to EF. Ordering by PATINDEX, name is another option, as alphas will return -1

Comment: I think I found a way to implement natural sorting with EF, check the updated answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the generated query, it's exactly as it should be. Your query asks for names that start with the exact string `[0-9]`.

`String.StartsWith(x)` is a *string* method that checks whether a string starts with a literal, without pattern matching. Linq to Entities translates this `LIKE 'x%'` where `x` is a literal string, not a pattern.  `[` is a special character in a LIKE statement though. This means that it has to be escaped with `LIKE '~[0-9]%' escape '~'`. The `LIKE` operator allows you to specify the escape character, in this case `~`.

I suspect that you didn't want names starting with `[0-9]` though, but those that start with a digit, ie `LIKE '[0-9]%'`. String.StartsWith doesn't support patterns nor is there another `String` method that does.

One solution is to use [SqlFunctions.PatIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.patindex(v=vs.110).aspx) in your query and filter for rows that return 1. I'd check the execution plan though, because I suspect the query will be slower. `LIKE '[0-9]%` is essentially a range search for all strings that start from `0` up to the letter after `9` excluding, ie `A`. This means that the server can use indexes on `Name`. With PATINDEX it may have to process all rows.

Unfortunately, `SqlFunctions` doesn't contain `Like` or any similar method that would generate a `LIKE` statement with pattern matching.

Another option is to actually ask for a range query with `a.Name >="0" && a.Name <"A"`.

**UPDATE - NATURAL SORTING**

This is a case of the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The actual problem X is how to perform natural sorting with LINQ to Entities. One of the T-SQL solutions for natural sorting is to use a formula in the ORDER BY clause *in combination with the name itself*, to make numbers appear after plain text, eg:

```
ORDER BY case when name like '[0-9]%' then 1 else 0 end, name
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work with EF because there is no equivalent to `LIKE` with patterns.

The same ordering can be performed with PATINDEX, which *is* available through the SqlFunctions.PatIndex function :

```
order by name, case when PATINDEX('[0-9]%',name)=1 then 1 else 0 end
```

The equivalent LINQ code could be:

```
query.OrderBy(a => {
                     SqlFunctions.PatIndex("[0-9]%",a.Name)==1? 1:0,
                     a.Name
                   })
```